# C#. Split string with dot after second char

Tags: c#

I'm really new to C# and I'm struggling with the below:

I need to convert int from 1231 to 31.12 if the input value has 4 characters.

```
public static int ConvertToStringWithDot(int input) 
{
   var result = input.ToString();

   if (result.Length < 5) 
   {
       result.Split    // how to proceed with splitting by dot after second character?
   }

   return result.Reverse
}
```

Is the way I approach the problem correct? Please help.

Comment: The easiest way is to construct it by accesing the string characters by index and adding a dot input[2]+input[3]+"."+input[0]+input[1]

Comment: and you should check Length == 4 not less than 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Split` is used to "split" a string in multiple parts **around a delimiter**. You do not *have* a delimiter - you're wanting to *insert* one. The simplest way is just to use [`Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring) to extract the two parts:

```
if (result.Length == 4) {
             //characters 2,3              characters 0,1
    result = result.Substring(2,2) + "." + result.Substring(0,2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your purpose is to convert the number, you don't have to use string operations, but a simple math like:

```
public static decimal ConvertToStringWithDot(int input)
    {
        if (input >= 1000 && input <= 9999)
        {
            int tmp1 = input / 100;
            int tmp2 = input % 100;
            var result = tmp2 + (decimal)(tmp1) / 100;
            return result;
        }
        return input;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
public static string ConvertToStringWithDot(int input)
{

  var result = input.ToString();

  if (result.Length == 4)
  {
    var firstPart = result.Substring(0, 2);
    var secondPart = result.Substring(2);
    return $"{secondPart}.{firstPart}";
  }
  return result;
}
```